# Replace Date part of time stamp in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns in DataFrame df:

```
date        time
5/25/2020.  5/25/2020 11:00:28 AM
5/6/2021.   7/7/2021. 11:00:28 AM
```

Now I want to create the new column as reference_time which will have date part of date column and time part of column time and attach timezone as US/Central. Like this:

```
date        time                         reference_time
5/25/2020.  5/25/2020 11:00:28 AM.       5/25/2021 11:00:28 AM US/Central 
5/6/2021.   7/7/2021. 11:10:28 AM        5/6/2021  11:10:28 US/Central
```

Could someone please help me in how to cleanly achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Are these datetime columns `date` and `time` or are they `strings`?

Comment: Is there a dot `.` after `date` field ?   Seen 3 out of 4 of source date fields have dots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for datetimes with [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`Series.dt.tz_localize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_localize.html):

```
df['reference_time'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time'].str.split(n=1).str[1])
                          .dt.tz_localize('US/Central'))
print (df)
        date                   time            reference_time
0  5/25/2020  5/25/2020 11:00:28 AM 2020-05-25 11:00:28-05:00
1   5/6/2021   7/7/2021 11:00:28 AM 2021-05-06 11:00:28-05:00
```

Solution for strings with join by `+`:

```
df['reference_time'] = df['date'] + ' ' + df['time'].str.split(n=1).str[1] + ' US/Central'
print (df)
        date                   time                    reference_time
0  5/25/2020  5/25/2020 11:00:28 AM  5/25/2020 11:00:28 AM US/Central
1   5/6/2021   7/7/2021 11:00:28 AM   5/6/2021 11:00:28 AM US/Central
```

If there are already datetimes in both columns:

```
df['reference_time'] = ((df['date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')))
                               .dt.tz_localize('US/Central'))
print (df)
        date                time            reference_time
0 2020-05-25 2020-05-25 11:00:28 2020-05-25 11:00:28-05:00
1 2021-05-06 2021-07-07 11:00:28 2021-05-06 11:00:28-05:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`Series.str.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
In [374]: df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['5/25/2020', '5/6/2021'], 'time':['5/25/2020 11:00:28 AM', '7/7/2021 11:00:28 AM']})

In [375]: df
Out[375]: 
        date                   time
0  5/25/2020  5/25/2020 11:00:28 AM
1   5/6/2021   7/7/2021 11:00:28 AM

In [384]: df['reference_time'] = df['date'] + ' ' + df['time'].str.split().str[-2:].str.join(' ') + ' US/Central'

In [385]: df
Out[385]: 
        date                   time                    reference_time
0  5/25/2020  5/25/2020 11:00:28 AM  5/25/2020 11:00:28 AM US/Central
1   5/6/2021   7/7/2021 11:00:28 AM   5/6/2021 11:00:28 AM US/Central
```